# Ionic 3 android generates BuildError.Error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

My ionic 3 config is 
 "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.1",
 "typescript": "2.4.2"

and dependencies are

"@angular/common": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",

My Ionic 3 project build successfully with

```
ionic cordova build --release android and
ionic cordova build android
```

But

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release and 
ionic cordova build android --release --prod
```

doesn't build, it generates error as

```
Error: ./node_modules/Rxjs/observable/BoundNodeCallbackObservable.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at Object.getEffectiveTypeAnnotationNode 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:9341:17)
at assignContextualParameterTypes 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41652:25)
at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41948:29)
at checkExpressionWorker 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42959:28)
at checkExpression 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42898:42)
at checkExpressionCached 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42779:38)
at checkReturnStatement 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45418:54)
at checkSourceElement 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46763:28)
at Object.forEach 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1506:30)
at checkBlock 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44563:16)
 @ ./node_modules/Rxjs/observable/bindNodeCallback.js 2:36-76
 @ ./node_modules/Rxjs/add/observable/bindNodeCallback.js
 @ ./node_modules/Rxjs/rx.js
 @ ./src/pages/page3/page3.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/Rxjs/observable/BoundCallbackObservable.js
 Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at Object.getEffectiveTypeAnnotationNode 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:9341:17)
at assignContextualParameterTypes 
 (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41652:25)
at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41948:29)
at checkExpressionWorker 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42959:28)
at checkExpression 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42898:42)
at checkExpressionCached 
 (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42779:38)
at checkReturnStatement 
 (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45418:54)
at checkSourceElement 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46763:28)
at Object.forEach 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1506:30)
at checkBlock 
(C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44563:16)
 @ ./node_modules/Rxjs/observable/bindCallback.js 2:32-68
 @ ./node_modules/Rxjs/add/observable/bindCallback.js
 @ ./node_modules/Rxjs/rx.js
 @ ./src/pages/page3/page3.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/app/main.ts
at BuildError.Error (native)
at new BuildError (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
at callback (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack.js:121:28)
at emitRecords.err (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:265:13)
at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:371:38)
at emitAssets.err (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:258:10)
at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:364:12)
at next (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:218:11)
at Compiler.compiler.plugin (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\node_modules\webpack\lib\performance\SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (C:\Users\JOHN\demoapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:222:13)
```

Comment: Could you show your `package.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `@ionic/app-scripts` `3.1.1`. That was a bug on `3.1.0`.

You can see it [**here**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1309#issuecomment-344036711)

Comment: It gives me error as => UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@4.4.0

Comment: Could you show the whole error message? Put that on your question above.

Comment: Could you use `"@ionic-native/core": "4.3.1",`. You need to remove `^`. You need to use like this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json After that remove `node_modules` folder and run `npm i`

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Did you do the above change on your `package.json` file?

Comment: Yes Sir.. after updating above changes I still get  UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@4.4.0 invalid
`-- @ionic/app-scripts@3.1.1

Comment: Which change have you done? Could you show your latest `package.json`?

Comment: I have updated all the errors in question after @ionic-native/core": "4.3.1 and @ionic/app-scripts 3.1.1.....

Comment: You need to use this configuration.: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json . No support yet for the Angular `5.0.1`.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)